# How can i resolve flake8 "unused import" error for pytest fixture imported from another module

Tags: python, pytest, flake8

I wrote pytest fixture in fixtures.py file and using it in my main_test.py . But I am getting this error in flake8: **F401 'utils_test.backup_path' imported but unused** for this code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def backup_path():
    ...
```

```
from fixtures import backup_path


def test_filename(backup_path):
    ...
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: But I am using that backup_path in `test_filename` function. If I do not import `backup_path` then `pytest` can't find the fixture.

Comment: I did simply `# noqa` at the end of the import line so I am ignoring this.

Comment: As an alternative you can specify path to your `fixtures.py` file in your `conftest.py` using list variable `pytest_plugins` like this: `pytest_plugins = ["some_package.fixtures"]`. Then you can use fixtures defined in this module without any imports

Answer (score 9, accepted):

generally **you should not do this**

making fixtures available via import side-effects is an unintentional implementation detail of how fixtures work and may break in the future of pytest

if you want to continue doing so, you can use `# noqa: F403` on the import, telling flake8 to ignore the unused imports (though the linter is telling you the right thing here!)

the supported way to make reusable fixtures is to place them in a `conftest.py` which is in a directory above all the tests that need it.  tests will have these fixtures "in scope" automatically

if that file is getting too large, you can write your fixtures in a plugin module and add that plugin module via `pytest_plugins = ['module.name']` in your `conftest.py`

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer, I'm also a pytest core dev

Comment: And what if there are no fixtures? If you are just running `import pytest` and `def test_simple_thing() -> None:` and mypy won't pass? Irritating to have to noqa it.

Comment: @rjurney ??? this SO post has nothing to do with mypy, and noqa has nothing to do with mypy as well

Comment: @anthony_sottile I understand you are frustrated or confused by my comment. I just want you to know... I love you anyway :D

Comment: During testing of an async project, I get a futures loop error when trying to import required libs for fixtures in conftest.py (works fine when importing to the pytest test file itself) so at this point I cannot put my fixtures in conftest.py. Because of this I ran into this issue and found this post. Looking for advice since my test file is massive and I really want to split it up using shared fixtures.